# Collecting multiple unknown inputs

Tags: python

Alright so this problem has been grinding me for a good hour. I am taking a zybooks course and I'm presented with the prompt,

Statistics are often calculated with varying amounts of input data. Write a program that takes any number of integers as input, and outputs the average and max.

Ex: If the input is:

15 20 0 5
the output is:

10 20
currently I have it 'working' with my code but the issue is I cannot figure out how to keep the input open for more or less inputs as zybooks runs through multiple different tests. i'm sure its something simple im overlooking. anything helps!

```
nums = []
for i in range(0, 4):
    number = int(input('Enter number'))
    nums.append(number)
avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
print(max(nums), avg)
```

Comment: Please be clear about the nature of the input -- is it all on one line, separated by spaces?  Or is each value on its own line, such that you calculate the statistics when the input stream is closed (most commonly when program is designed to have its input delivered via a pipe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code continually asks the user to enter values until they enter a blank (just press enter without typing).

This is the code:

```
nums = []

# initialse
number = 0
# loop until there isn't an input
while number != "":
    # ask for user input
    number = input('Enter number:')
    # validate the input isn't blank
    # prevents errors
    if number != "":
        # make input integer and add it to list
        nums.append(int(number))

avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
print(max(nums), avg)
```

Alternatively, if you have the list of numbers:

```
def maxAndAvg(nums):
    avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
    return max(nums), avg
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have the user specify how many numbers they want to take the average of.  For instance:

```
nums = []
n = int(input('How many numbers: '))
for i in range(n):
    number = int(input('Enter number: '))
    nums.append(number)
avg = sum(nums) / n
print(max(nums), avg)
```

Alternatively, if you want a function that itself takes a variable number of arguments, you'll need to use the "*args" operator. For instance,

```
def my_average(*args):
    return sum(args)/len(args)
```

An example usage:

```
print(my_average(1),my_average(1,2),my_average(1,2,3))
```

Result:

```
1.0 1.5 2.0
```

Comment: I have looked into that. the issue is my code isn't being checked by an instructor it is being ran through a program with predetermined inputs. so that 15 20 0 5 is just the set list it gives me, but the program itself can hit me with other numbers and a shorter or longer list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys this is the correct code to figure this lab out. Did some data mining and some line manipulation to pass all ten tests:

```
nums = []

while not nums:
    number = input()
    nums = [int(x) for x in number.split() if x]
avg = int(sum(nums) / len(nums))

print(avg, max(nums))
```